# twilio 160 vs 1600 characters

Tags: java, twilio

Here is my code

```
try {
  twilioConnect();
  com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account account = client.getAccount();
  SmsFactory smsFactory = account.getSmsFactory();
  Map<String, String> smsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
  smsParams.put("To", "+" + phone);
  smsParams.put("From", TWILIO_SERVER_PHONE_NUMBER); 
  smsParams.put("Body", mymessage);
  Sms sms = smsFactory.create(smsParams);
} catch (TwilioRestException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can my code send the up to 1600 characters mentioned on [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters) or is there a different code for that? If the method is different, will someone please present something as clear as my snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to send up to 1,600 characters, but beware that it may send as multiple messages of 160 characters.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about `MessageFactory`?

Comment: no. It's not. And I am not sure why. Maybe it's because I have comcast and it's down almost more than it is up. But I keep trying to see what's going on.

Comment: @KatedralPillon what in particular is happening? If you send <160 characters does something different happen?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use that API. Instead, switch to:

```
Account account = client.getAccount();
MessageFactory factory = account.getMessageFactory();

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", from));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to)); 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", body));    
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallback", statusCallback));

Message msg = factory.create(params);
```